# Trigger rebuild when .html file is changed

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

I have a folder `Components` inside a ASP.NET Core (6,7 or 8) app which contains `.html` files and I want to trigger the rebuild of the Application when one of these files is changed.

I added this to my `.csproj` file but neither `dotnet run` nor `dotnet watch run` did rebuild on file change:

```xml
<ItemGroup>
   <Content Update="Components/SomeFolder/SomeFile.html" Watch="true" CopyToOutputDirectory="PreserveNewest" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Comment: Just wonder if only a static file is updated why do you need to trigger a build. Maybe for what you are trying to achieve can be solved in another way.

Comment: It's processed within the application

Comment: could you try using this code`<ItemGroup>
        <Content Update="Components/**/*.html" Watch="true" CopyToOutputDirectory="PreserveNewest" />
      </ItemGroup>`  here is the official document : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/dotnet-watch?view=aspnetcore-6.0#customize-files-list-to-watch

Comment: This is what I actually tried before and it didn't work also.

Comment: @JalpaPanchal the linked posted for `dotnet watch` solved it.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77799198/trigger-rebuild-when-html-file-is-changed?noredirect=1#comment137155938_77799198) by @JalpaPanchal I solved it for `dotnet watch run` using this `ItemGroup` definition:

```xml
<ItemGroup>
  <Watch Include="Components\**\*.html" />
</ItemGroup>
```